# .NET Core parse Dictionary<string,string> [FromQuery]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have strange problem with parsing object in Rest API.
When I have Controller like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCurrencyRateAsync([FromQuery] Dictionary<string,string> param)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Everything is Ok, my JSON is parsing correctly, but when I have object with dictionary:

```
public class CustomFilter
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> param{ get; set; }
}
```

and my controller in `[FromQuery]` takes this object:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCurrencyRateAsync([FromQuery] CustomFilter filter)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

My dictionary is not parsing. What is wrong with this?

Comment: What query string are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the query string you are sending. This setup works fine for me in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> mod { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

[HttpGet("test1")]
public IActionResult Test1([FromQuery]Dictionary<string, string> mod)
{
    return Ok();
}

        
[HttpGet("test2")]
public IActionResult Test2([FromQuery] MyClass mc)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The first one successfully binds for urls:

- `.../test1?mod[someKey]=someValue`
- `.../test1?[someKey]=someValue`

Second one for:

- `.../test2?mc.mod[someKey]=someValue`
- `.../test2?mod[someKey]=someValue`

But fails for `.../test2?[someKey]=someValue`.

Comment: Thanks! it works. I was sending wrong JSON: [someKey]=someValue. With mod[someKey]=someValue it passed.

Comment: @Arkady was glad to help!