# Dictionary <string, object> in query params - value is always null

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-core, query-string

```
public class MyObject {
 public Dictionary<string, dynamic> myDictionary;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyEndPoint([FromQuery] MyObject params)
```

I'm trying to send param query values using postman but the value of the dictionary is always null.
Can `dynamic` be used in a query?

Comment: `dynamic` is nearly always the wrong type.   Either use `object`, `string `or even better, the actual type you are expecting.  Also, can you show the postman query string?  I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core parse Dictionary<string,string> \[FromQuery\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946426/net-core-parse-dictionarystring-string-fromquery)

Comment: The type can change so I don't to use string. ```object``` doesn't work either. Postman query: ```MyEndPoint?myDictionary.myKey=1```

Comment: You are sending the wrong format in your query. The types will always be string, even if you use dynamic or object.   .NET doesn't try parsing every parameter to see if it's an int, long, or float, they just converted to string, UNLESS you have a more specific type in your dictionary.